# Not able to load a DEM raster into Spatialite

Tags: dem, spatialite, rgb, rasterlite

I am using Spatialite to store a DEM raster with terrain values (GMTED2010 from Nasa). To be more precise, I am using the version: spatialite_gui-1.7.1-win-x86.zip plus rasterlite_load (rasterlite_tool-1.1g-win-x86.zip) and rasterlite_pyramid (rasterlite_pyramid-1.1g-win-x86.zip). The problem is that the DEM raster gets into Spatialite as an RGB raster, so it does not longer have the associated altitude values but 3 values (RGB) per pixel instead, which makes the appearance of a greyscale DEM but without heights!. I am using the following syntax:

```
rasterlite_load -d GMTED2010.sqlite -T raster -D . -i tiff
```

So, I thought Spatialite handled the type of raster, but apparently it only uses RGB types, doesn´t it?

What I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Rasterlite 1.1g version (released on 2013-05-05) (https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/librasterlite/index) is no longer maintained. This version cannot handle with the example above, it has not been implemented.

Fortunately, Rasterlite2 version 1.0.0-rc0 (released on 2014-07-30) is much more powerful and can handle Int16 DEM GeoTiff images with success (https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/librasterlite2/index), like the raster above. So, height values are stored properly into the database.

Answer (score 2):

rasterlite_load does have logic to handle imagery other than RGB, but it may not deal with your situation.

From the code, the supported combinations are:

- `bits_per_sample == 1 && samples_per_pixel == 1`, interpreted as a CCITT 4 fax.
- `bits_per_sample == 8 && samples_per_pixel == 1 && photometric == 3`, interpreted as paletted image (i.e. colour lookup table)
- `bits_per_sample == 8 && samples_per_pixel == 1 && photometric < 2`, interpreted as grayscale
- `samples_per_pixel >= 3`, interpreted as RGB

Note that rasterlite_load is a convenience tool for common cases for RasterLite databases, and is distinct from SpatiaLite.

One option would be to modify rasterlite_load to handle your specific case. Sandro is pretty good at accepting patches!

Comment: Could I upload the DEM into Spatialite by using SQL syntax instead? How would the sentence be?

Comment: You could upload it if you create the BLOB yourself.